# Class diagram for a room reservation: use of inheritance?

Tags: inheritance, uml, class-diagram, class-design

I'm creating a class diagram for a room reservation system. There is an option of creating a regular reservation (for example every Tuesday in March). I´m wondering whether I should design a specific class like this:

[image]

Comment: I think this case might be a candidate for the composite pattern.

Comment: What is the difference between start/end vs. date/duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Should I design a specific class? **Maybe**
- Like this? **No**

Whether to use inheritance or not is IMHO a cost/benefit question.

When implementing inheritance there is usually some cost involved in terms of extra classes, tables, documentation and other results that need to be created after the decision to use inheritance.

Inheritance is about special and general cases. First you might want to ask what is the difference between the cases - (called a discriminator). In your case it is the type of reservation and you could avoid the inheritance by modelling this type of reservation and implementing the different behavior based on the reservation type. That would lead to a design like:

**Avoiding inheritance**

[image: Avoiding Inheritance]

If the inheritance has a high benefit because there are a lot of extra attributes, relation or operations for each special case then you can apply it.

In this case there is

- an extra 1:n relation between regular reservation and reservation (which was not visible in your design but implied by the attribute regular Reservation)

and there are some extra fields

- start date
- end date
- frequency

What is missing at this time is common behavior that would make it sensible to apply inheritance. In the image below I added the generalization nevertheless. It would not be needed at this point in time but as soon as there are general operations you would like to apply to any type of reservation:

**Applying inheritance**

[image: Applying inheritance]

Comment: You can find the plantuml sources of this answer at http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/UML#Inheritance

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely not model the collection as a subclass of the single. If anything, the inheritance relationship runs the other direction: a `Reservation` is a special kind of `Regular Reservation` where `startDate == endDate` and `frequency == 1`.

But then why even model two classes? Consider that all reservations are regular. Conceptually, a `Reservation` is a collection containing only one item. A `Regular Reservation` is a collection containing multiple items.

Answer (score 1):

#### Isn't this design seriously flawed ?

Inheritance should not be used just as a trick for reusing some class members.  If  `RegularReservation` would inherit from `Reservation`, it would mean that a regular reservation IS SOME KIND OF simple reservation. Is this the really case ? For example what about the single `Date` of `Reservation` : has a date.  Does it have any meaning for a regular reservation ?

So there are some flaws here:

- it imposes a useless part of the (private) interface (`date` member)  to all kind of reservations, even when it makes no sense. This is against the **[Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)**
- the base class must know about the inheriting classes (`regular_reservation` member).  So if tomorrow you'd wanted to create a `MultipleReservation` (several unrelated dates), you'd need to modify the base class again.  This is against the **[Open Close Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle)**
- classes using `Reservation` would need to know the details about the different kind of reservations to handle their specific abilities.  This is against the **[Principle of the least knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)**.

#### What problem do you want to solve ?

The challenge for a room reservation system is not only to register reservations, but also to know for each given time slot if the room is free or if there's already a reservation.

Consequences:

- You must be able to get all the occurrences of a regular reservation in a given time interval.
- You should decide whether occurrences of a regular reservation are single reservations, or whether single and regular reservation should both have some kind of occurence objects.

#### Proposed design

An abstract `Reservation` is always about a `Client` booking a `Room` with a price for one or several `TimeSlots`. `TimeSlots` are only about dates, time, duration.  This helps to ensure a separation of concerns:

[image: abstract reservation composed of time slots]

The number of slots and how these are created will depend on the kind of `Reservation`. But the general principle is that deleting a reservation would delete all its time slots (ok:  what if there are slots in the past ?).

You may also have some general methods:

- `getAllSlots()` would return the full collection of time slots
- `getSlotsInInterval(startDate, endDate)` would return only those time slots in the interval

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing a single *Reservation* abstract class in this case, and creating two sub classes from that, **SingleReservation** and **RecurringReservation** [as shown in this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrpwg.png):

[image]

This will help your business logic determine how to handle each reservation, and prevent the use of null-able columns in your database.

Comment: It is indeed a good idea to look for the common denominator.  However, your API gives the impression that every reservation has one date.  If for example you had a GUI to show graphically all the bookings in a month, how would it know that a given `Reservation` may have several days ? Can you refactor it to be LSP and LoD compliant ?

Comment: Your UML notation is off. The arrows in your diagram are not Generalizations.